# Conversion of list of nullables to list of objects

Tags: c#

Why is the second conversion failing with

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'.
```

```
object list1 = new List<string>() { "a", "b" };
object list2 = new List<bool?>() { true, false };

IEnumerable<object> bind1 = (IEnumerable<object>)list1;
IEnumerable<object> bind2 = (IEnumerable<object>)list2;
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` is a value type, and [generic covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) doesn't apply for value types (so there's no conversion from `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<object>` either, for example):

> Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the resulting constructed type.

The simplest fix would be to use `Cast`:

```
IEnumerable<object> bind2 = list2.Cast<object>();
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I though bool? is treated as a reference type by C#.

Comment: @daniel.tekle: Nope - it's still a value type, even though it has a null value. Separate those two concepts.

Answer (score 3):

See [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17575013/1894317) for the reasons, he'll explain it far better than I ever could.

The easiest fix is to use the [`Enumerable.Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) extension method:

```
using System.Linq;

object list1 = new List<string>() { "a", "b" };
object list2 = new List<bool?>() { true, false };

IEnumerable<object> bind1 = list1.Cast<Object>();
IEnumerable<object> bind2 = list2.Cast<Object>();
```